# How to check, that there are rows with each id from set?

Tags: sql, postgresql, exists

I have set of `ids`. For example, `12, 3, 6, 10`. I need to check, that each of these `ids` are existed (actually, I have complex `WHERE` condition, but it does not matter).

So, I can execute **N** queries, like this:

```
SELECT 1 FROM tbl WHERE id=12;
SELECT 1 FROM tbl WHERE id=3;
SELECT 1 FROM tbl WHERE id=6;
SELECT 1 FROM tbl WHERE id=10;
```

Or I can execute one query, but it contains slow `GROUP BY and COUNT(*)`:

```
SELECT id, COUNT(*)
WHERE id IN (12, 3, 6, 10)
GROUP BY id
```

Is there more fast way to check, that all rows with some `WHERE condition` are existed, without using of `GROUP BY`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `GROUP BY` should be fine.  However, I would recommend `DISTINCT ON` for this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (id) id, 1
WHERE id IN (12, 3, 6, 10)
ORDER BY id;
```

Comment: oh, I did not know about `DISTINCT ON`. Thank you! Can you explain, why you `SELECT ... 1`?

Comment: @Max . . . The `1` is returned by the query in your question.